# C# ulong overflow / underflow somehow allowed

Tags: c#, integer, overflow, underflow, ulong

I'm a little confused about the behavior of the `ulong` type. I understand it to be a [64-bit integer used for positive numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ulong) (max value 18,446,744,073,709,551,615). I just started using it because I need really big positive numbers, but there's some strange behavior I don't understand around potential negative numbers.

```
ulong big = 1000000;    //Perfectly legal

ulong negative = -1;    //"Constant value "-1" cannot be converted to a ulong" Makes sense


//Attempt to sneak around the -1 as a constant compile-time error
int negativeInt = -1;
ulong negativeUlongFail = negativeInt;    //"Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'ulong'.
                                 //An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
//So I add casting
ulong negativeUlong = (ulong)negativeInt;    //But this yields 18446744073709551615

//Try and get a negative number indirectly
ulong number = 0;
number = number - 10;  //now number is 18446744073709551615 but no underflow error
```

**What's going on? How come some underflow errors are caught and others aren't and don't even throw exceptions? Can I detect these?**

I focused on getting negative numbers by underflowing, but I've seen similar things when getting numbers bigger than the max value and overflowing.

*I'm not sure if they're technically Errors or Exceptions, so please forgive me if I used incorrect terminology*

Comment: The compiler has under/overflow checking enabled by default, the runtime does not.  The latter is a project setting, Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button.  Turning on the checkbox is a good idea for the Debug configuration.  Not so much for the Release build, the check is pretty expensive.  Override these defaults on-the-fly with the `checked` and `unchecked` keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want the underflow (or overflow) exception to be thrown, try this instead :-

```
checked
{
    ulong number = 0;
    number = number - 10;
}
```

by default the exception gets swallowed (it runs in unchecked).

see official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked