# Substraction of two ulong giving wrong output

Tags: c#, binary, ulong

```
DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan currentTs = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
ulong serverTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(currentTs.TotalSeconds);
ulong requestTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(requestTimeStamp);
ulong r = (serverTotalSeconds - requestTotalSeconds);
if (r > requestMaxAgeInSeconds)
{
     return true;
}
```

The above c# code sometimes giving the wrong subtracted value.

For example, for following values

```
serverTotalSeconds = 1615184795
requestTotalSeconds = 1615184796

"r" is returning value 18446744073709551615
```

I am not able to understand the cause of the issue. Can somebody point out what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Why not use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds` to get the Unix epoch timestamp?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270715/c-sharp-ulong-overflow-underflow-somehow-allowed)

Comment: from where `requestTimeStamp` is coming?

Comment: What value do you expect `r` to hold as a result of that calculation?

Comment: Using an `unsigned long` and then going negative leads to this behaviour. It would be the same, if you take `(ulong)0 - (ulong)1`. If a result can be negative you have to use a signed type (e.g. `long`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is expected. the difference is -1. which can be represented as in 8 bytes as `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary and this is equivalent to `18446744073709551615` in decimal.

If you use `long` in place of `unsigned` `long`. it will give you the expected result if you are expecting the different to be negative also.